Disabling Tello's Visual Positioning System (VPS) and Downward-Facing Camera with Python for VICON Integration
I'm working with a Tello drone and would like to disable the Visual Positioning System (VPS), which relies on the downward-facing camera. My goal is to use a VICON system for more precise positioning and tracking.
I have tried tello.set_downward_sensor(False) under djitellopy library for disabling VPS, but it was not working.
And I have tried to make a function for it by:
def disable_vps(drone):
    """Disables the Visual Positioning System (VPS) on a Tello drone

    Args:
        drone (Tello): An already connected Tello object
    """
    drone.set_downward_sensor(False)

and calling it by disable_vps(tello), but I still get error for it.
Is there a Python-based solution to specifically turn off the Tello's downward-facing camera? I want to ensure that the drone doesn't rely on VPS data and prioritizes the VICON system for positioning.
